# MYSQL SELECT COUNT returns error

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this `MYSQL`-query?:

```
SELECT REPLACE( FORMAT( COUNT (*) , 0 ) ,  ',',  '.' ) AS total_videos FROM videos
```

this gives me an SQL error...

thanks in advance...

Comment: And _what_ error do you get? Or are we meant to _guess_ that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Space should not be count(*).

```
SELECT REPLACE( FORMAT( COUNT(*) , 0 ) ,  ',',  '.' ) AS total_videos FROM videos
```